# Existance and uniqueness for diverging and converging integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f\in C[a,b]$ and $y_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f(y_0)=0$ and $f(y) \neq 0$ for any $y\in [a,b]$,$y\neq y_0$. Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that if both $\int_{a}^{y_0}\frac{du}{fu},\int_{y_0}^{b}\frac{du}{f(u)}$ are divergent, then $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point of existence and local uniqueness of $y'=f(y)$. If at least one of the two integrals converge, then $y_0$ is a singular solution for $y'=f(y)$.

My approach was to choose a integral, $F(y)=\int_{y_0}^{y}\frac{du}{f(u)}$,$y\in\mathbb{R}$. For a solution $\phi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ I obtain that $F(\phi(x))=x+c$ and, more, $F(\phi(x))=x-x_0$ and so $I\subset I+x_0$. But the limits of $F$ as $y\rightarrow a$ is negative infinity and for y towards $b$ positive infinity, so I can argue that $I=\mathbb{R}$. I don`t know how to end it from here.

Comment: You have that mixed up. The singularity is at $y_0$, so you have to take out that midpoint from the integration, and the limits $y\to y_0$ give infinity. You have to treat $(a,y_0)$ and $(y_0,b)$ separately. Or argue that both are similar, so that treating one case is sufficient.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula Kindly respond to the above comment. It is helpful if you ask the user to write an answer if you are satisfied with the explanation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you Teresa, I shall do this because I want an answer.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The explanation is good but I would like a full answer and in that case I give the bounty.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula Welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singularity is at $y_0$, thus you get that
$$
\lim_{y\to y_0}\int_a^y\frac{du}{f(u)}=\pm\infty
$$
the sign depending on the sign of $f$ on $[a,y_0)$. The sign is certain as $y_0$ is the only root of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Now continue as proposed, with $F$ you get $F(y(t))-F(a)=t-t_a$, and as $F$ is a monotonic function, it has an inverse. If $f$ is positive on $[a,y_0)$, then $F$ is growing towards infinity, $F(y(t))=F(a)+t-t_a$ is solvable for $a<y(t)<y_0$ for any $t>t_a$. So at no time can the level $y_0$ be reached.

In the case where that integral is finite, one gets that at the finite time $t=t_a+F(y_0)-F(a)$ the line $y=y_0$ is reached, so that there is no uniqueness at that line.

---

The situation on the other side $(y_0,b)$ is similar for negative $f$. With a switched sign in $f$, one has to consider the behavior of the function for falling $t$ values.